# CASE with IS NULL not replacing as expected

Tags: mysql

I have a simple column with some numbers, which looks like;

```
133
8
55
11
NULL
NULL
235
NULL
```

I want to put a default in when selecting this column, with the aim of replacing the nulls. I've done;

```
 CASE
        WHEN round(avg(s.seconds)) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE round(avg(s.seconds))

 END as 'seconds'
```

However, my nulls remain. My expectation is that they would be set to 0. Why would this not work?

Comment: Unsure what you're doing with AVG there, but have a look at COALESCE - it will probably solve your issues.

Comment: @Bing, COALESCE seems to return the first non-null value, i wish to replace the nulls with a default. Not sure if COALESCE suits that purpose.

Comment: `SELECT AVG(COALESCE(s.seconds, 0)) AS seconds` perhaps? Again, not sure if you want the average of the entire column or what you're going for.

Comment: `AVG`, like the other aggregate functions, already ignores `NULL` values, so you should not even need to use `COALESCE` if all you want is the average of the column.  Please show us your expected output.

Comment: The full SQL would allow better judgement, but `AVG` aggregates the result without `GROUP BY`. Thus the `CASE` would not return `NULL`.

Comment: Maybe `IFNULL(round(avg(s.seconds)),0)` ?

Answer (score 1):

NULL values are ignored in average calculations.

If you want to replace NULL values for 0 in your average, you need to use COALESCE on the values, inside the average function. Example follows:

```sql
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP1;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP1
SELECT 1 AS price
UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS price
UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS price
UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS price;

SELECT * FROM TEMP1; # List values (1, NULL, NULL, 3)
SELECT AVG(price) FROM TEMP1; # Returns 2 (NULL values IGNORED)
SELECT AVG(COALESCE(price,0)) FROM TEMP1; # Returns 1 (NULL values REPLACED with 0)
```

Comment: Good explanation, but your code is confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it by 3 ways**

**1**

```
round(avg(CASE
               WHEN s.seconds IS NULL THEN 0
               ELSE s.seconds
           END)) as 'seconds'
```

**2**

> The MySQL **IFNULL()** function lets you return an alternative value if an
>   expression is NULL:

```
round(avg(IFNULL(s.seconds,0)))
```

**3**

> or we can use the **COALESCE()** function, like this:

```
 round(avg(COALESCE(s.seconds,0)))
```

Comment: None of these seem to work. I imagine something else in the full query is interfering. I'll have to dig a bit more.

Comment: Post the full query then, or at least the desired result from the limited sample data you provided.